# iPhone: Is there any way of how to PDF pages Scroll In UIScrollview like paging in Leaves Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf-reader

I have a Leaves view (Tom Brow's leaves project) to simulate curling effect for PDF pages.

now i want to implement in Leaves project page only scrolling like paging i was refund vfr-Reader project but it is hard coding and i can not understood how to implements in Leaves project.

please can anyone guide me how to do this stuff in Leaves project PDF page scroll paging (not curl)

Comment: The below link will help you, for PDF view and basic operations. [http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/reading-displaying-pdf-documents/](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/reading-displaying-pdf-documents/) **--
K.D**